# "Cannot resolve symbol" in Intellij IDEA 12.1.6+ Gradle 1.9

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to Gradle and am trying to set it up in my development environment (Windows 7 + Intellij IDEA 12.1.6). Hence, according to the `getting stated guide` of gradle.org, I have installed Gradle 1.9.

```
PS C:\work> gradle -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-11-19 08:20:02 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     7970ec3503b4f5767ee1c1c69f8b4186c4763e3d

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.6.0_26 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.1-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

In addition, I have installed **Intellij Gradle plugin**.

Now, the problem is that when I open a `*.gradle` file in Intellij IDEA (version 12.1.6), it complains that *"can not resolve symbol X"* where X  is any keyword of Gradle DSL (see screenshot below).

[image]

I highly appreciate if anyone can tell me how to fix this issue or point me to documentation which address this issue.

#### Update 1:

Note that I have tried with Intellij IDEA 13 (EAP) as well. Unfortunately, same problem is reproducible there.

Comment: IntelliJ tries to help you, but it can't because it doesn't know the DSL well enough. Ignore those errors, and check that the build file works as expected. That's what matters.

Comment: Thanks. Build is working fine.  My concern was whether I have configured gradle correctly or not. I was wondering whether it is known issue with IDEA 12.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent IntelliJ 13 EAPs, IntelliJ understands much of the core build script language, including the `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks. If it doesn't work for you, perhaps get in touch with the folks from JetBrains.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have tried with the recent IDEA 13 EAP and got the same result. I basically tried in two ways however same problem persists: [1] I tried to import `java/quickstart` sample from Gradle 1.9.1 distribution. [2] used `apply plugin:idea` to generate all idea related meta and tried to open it in IDEA.

Comment: 1. is the way to go to get content assist. Perhaps try with the Gradle wrapper (that's what I did) or contact JetBrains.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look into `gradlewrapper`.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Content assist has been improved with IDEA 13 EAP. It can detect `task` and `repositories` tokens and can resolve their definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with 2017.1. It turns out that the project had somehow become configured to use a local gradle distribution, and the Gradle Home directory was pointing to a path that didn't exist anymore. Once I pointed IntelliJ to the correct path for the gradle distribution, the correct highlighting was enabled again.

To check this, open the Settings window and navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle. Make sure you are using the correct settings that point IntelliJ to a valid gradle installation. In my case (shown below) I am using the gradle wrapper. If you are using a local install, make sure the Gradle home path is specified correctly on this screen.

[image: Screenshot of the Gradle Settings window]